# What is the purpose of this filter, impedance adaptation and virtual ground circuit?

Tags: diodes, analog, signal

I encounter this circuit link to a pcb that I used :

[image]

with VGND_FIXED defined as :
[image]

And AVDD defined as :

[image]

As I understand it, the usb provide the AVDD (1.8V).
The AVDD is then used to set the Virtual Ground (VGND_FIXED) at 1.8V pulling up the "floating ground" of the sensor.

Then there is some protection diodes (I'm not sur about this one) an impedance conversion circuit with a first opamp and a second one used as a filter.

My question is, did I guessed well the purpose of this circuit ?

What is the exact consequence of the diodes on the signal ?

For instance, the sensor I used with this circuit sent a voltage between -1V and 1V if I measure the voltage between its signal pin and its virtual ground.

If I plug this sensor on this circuit, what should be the resulting voltage between virtual ground (VGND_FIXED) and sensor2 output (SENSOR2_OUT) ?

The diode should keep it over 0V ? or is it still possible to have a negative voltage difference ?

Comment: _"As I understand it, the usb provide the AVDD (**1.8V**). The AVDD is then used to set the Virtual Ground (VGND_FIXED) at 1.8V"_ - Something is wrong here. AVDD should should be about 2 x VGND. Are you sure the LP5907 is the 1.8V version (SOT-23 device marking LLUB), not the 3.3V version (LLVB)?

Comment: Pretty sure it's the 1.8V version, I got exactly 1.8V at the AVDD of the pcb. Why should it be 3V ?

Comment: REF3318 puts out 1.8V, and needs more than 1.8V to operate. Virtual ground is usually set to ~1/2 supply voltage. Having it equal to the supply voltage doesn't make sense. What output voltage range do you get? Does it work properly? Can you show us a photo of the board?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show you the board for know.I get almost the same range in output except it don't go under 0V. I will add pictures of the signal input and output asap.

Comment: This result is when I use my computer as 5VDC input. When I used another 5V power supply (laboratory power supply for instance) the signal is almost exactly like the one in input. I don't know why there is such differences between power supplies . I don't know how it should work exactly so it's hard to find out where is the problem (maybe there is absolutely no problem)